# How to write to a void pointer without knowing the Data Type?

Tags: c, adt, dynamic-memory-allocation, void-pointers

I am trying to write the code for a generic Stack using Singly Linked List in C. I am trying to use `(void *)` as the data type in each of its functions like:

`node* getNode(void *, size_t);`

`void append(node **, size_t);` etc.

The structure for each node is:

```
typedef struct linked_list{
void *data;
struct linked_list *next; }node;
```

In the `getNode` function mentioned above I am trying to do this:

```
node* getNode(void *data, size_t data_size) {
   node *newNode;
   newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
   newNode->next = NULL;
  // this line should assign the void *data to the data part of the node
   return newNode;}
```

I could not find how to assign the data part without knowing the data type, but only using the `data_size` variable. I found out about the `memcopy` function, but even that requires the data type.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to save a pointer to the data, you can just copy the pointer:

```
newNode->data = data;
```

If you want to copy what it points to, you need `malloc` to get the memory and `memcpy` to copy the bytes:

```
newNode->data = malloc(data_size);
memcpy(newNode->data, data, data_size);
```

The signature of `memcpy` is:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

It's meant to copy generic memory, so you can pass it a `void *` for both the source and destination.

Comment: Doesn't `memcpy` require data type?